# Error accepting MCC invitation with API Adwords PHP

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm having some trouble accepting a sent MCC link invitation with PHP.

The MCC account is not the top-level account, it is a sub MCC.

I can send the invitation correctly (from account 9547216945 to client 1096054675) usign the API, the problem is when I use Oauth2 to access on behalf of that client and try to accept the invitation.

Supose I have sent the invitation with no problem.

I'm doing test using an Adwords account of my own, so that is my test client.

Then I follow next steps to accept:

## File: test.php

```
$clientId     = "834249844................ak68sd6t.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$clientSecret = "uJdPPC..............CN";
$callbackUrl  = "http://example.com/test.php";
 

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'redirectUri' => $callbackUrl,
    'clientId' => $clientId,
    'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords', 
]);


if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $oauth2->setState(sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1024)));
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $oauth2->getState();

    // Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
    $config = [ 'access_type' => 'offline', 'prompt' => 'consent'];

    header('Location: ' . $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri($config));
    exit;
}
elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state.');
} 
else {
    $oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
    $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();

    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
      ->withClientId($clientId)
      ->withClientSecret($clientSecret)
      ->withRefreshToken($authToken['refresh_token'])
      ->build()
    ;

    // Construct an API session configured from the OAuth2 credentials above.
    $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->withDeveloperToken("m2l..........Vq3g")
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->withClientCustomerId("1096054675") 
        ->build()
    ;

    $adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
    $linkOp = new LinkOperation();
    $link = new ManagedCustomerLink();
    $link->setClientCustomerId('1096054675');
    $link->setManagerCustomerId('9547216945');
    $link->setLinkStatus(LinkStatus::ACTIVE);
    $linkOp->setOperand($link);
    $linkOp->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
    
    $managedCustomerService = $adWordsServices->get($session, ManagedCustomerService::class);
    $result = $managedCustomerService->mutateLink([$linkOp]);
}
```

That script makes me login into the client account (the one that I'm using for testing purpose), then I use that client refresh token with Oauth2, and when I want to accept the previous sent invitation, I get this error:

[ManagedCustomerServiceError.NOT_AUTHORIZED @ operations[0]]

I tried to make it work multiple times with no success, anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

## [RESOLVED]

The problem was that I have to use

```
$linkOp->setOperator(Operator::SET)
```

instead of

```
$linkOp->setOperator(Operator::ADD)
```

In order to accept an existing pending invitation.